# Office, Save to SharePoint, Locations ... Add Delete from list

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, office-2010

In Word under the Save to SharePoint there are Locations and Recent Locations.

How can I manually add to the list of Locations.

Well ideally I want to do this via code or script so for every user in the company they have the default set of libraries already set up.  Asking them to browse through SharePoint is not only slow, but tedious.

I assume that list must be stored locally somewhere and I could potentially edit that local file to control the list?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am no guru, but by copying exporting an existing registry entry for a site, and then modifying it, and then merging it in, I can add sites.  Typing in Regeditor or similar would like do as well.  Here is an example where a merged in a Shared Document Library.  So by creating your default entries, you could add them.  If there is a better way or solution you have found, let us know!

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Server Links\Published\My Site\Shared]
"LinkType"=hex(b):02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"IsMember"=dword:00000001
"IsPublished"=dword:00000001
"Url"="https://mysite.company.com/Shared Documents"
```